# Yii2: Apply different AccessRule filter to specific actions in the same controller

Tags: yii2

Is it possible to have two different rule sets `\yii\filters\AccessRule` in `behaviors()` to control different actions? Something like:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [

        // Standard access
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['create'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
        ],

        // fancy access
        'accessView' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'ruleConfig' => [
                'class' => MyFancyAccessRule::className(),
            ],
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['view'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

In this case I want a different access rule to apply to the `view` action as it has an extra check...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can attach the same behavior multiple times like in your example (`AccessControl` is a behavior for controlling access to specified action).

But you don't need to. You can use only one `AccessControl` behavior and configure your rule directly in `rules` config:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['create'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
                [
                    'class' => MyFancyAccessRule::className(),
                    'actions' => ['view'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```